# What are the differences between Either and Option?

Tags: scala

According to the [documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc2/scala/Either.html):

> A common use of Either is as an alternative to Option for dealing
>    with possible missing values.

Why would you use one over the other?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The nice thing about `Either` is that you can keep track of the *reason* something is missing.  For example, if you were working with `Options`, you might be in a situation like this:

```
val xOpt = Option(1)
val yOpt = Option(2)
val zOpt = None

val tupled = for {
    x <- xOpt
    y <- yOpt
    z <- zOpt
} yield (x, y, z)
```

Now, if `tupled` is `None`, we don't really know why!  If this is an important detail for the rest of the behavior, using `Either` can help:

```
val tupled = for {
    x <- xOpt.toRight("x is missing").right
    y <- yOpt.toRight("y is missing").right
    z <- zOpt.toRight("z is missing").right
} yield (x, y, z)
```

This will return either `Left(msg)` where the message is the first missing value's corresponding message, or `Right(value)` for the tupled value.  It is conventional to keep use `Left` for failures and `Right` for successes.

Of course, you can also use `Either` more broadly, not only in situations with missing or exceptional values.  There are other situations where `Either` can help express the semantics of a simple union type.

The third common idiom to use for exceptional values is the `Try` monad:

```
val xTry = Try("1".toInt)
val yTry = Try("2".toInt)
val zTry = Try("asdf".toInt)

val tupled = for {
    x <- xTry
    y <- yTry
    z <- zTry
} yield (x, y, z)
```

`Try[A]` is isomorphic to `Either[Throwable, A]`.  In other words you can treat a `Try` as an `Either` with a left type of `Throwable`, and you can treat any `Either` that has a left type of `Throwable` as a `Try`.  Also `Option[A]` is homomorphic to `Try[A]`.  So you can treat an `Option` as a `Try` that ignores errors.  Therefore you can also transitively think it as an `Either`.  In fact, the standard library supports some of these transformations:

```
//Either to Option
Left[Int, String](1).left.toOption //Some(1)
Right[Int, String]("foo").left.toOption //None

//Try to Option
Try("1".toInt).toOption //Some(1)
Try("foo".toInt).toOption //None

//Option to Either
Some(1).toRight("foo") //Right[String, Int](1)
(None: Option[Int]).toRight("foo") //Left[String, Int]("foo")
```

Since Scala 2.12, the standard library does include the conversions from `Either` to `Try`, from `Try` to `Either`, but not from `Option` to `Try`. For earlier versions, it is pretty simple to enrich `Option`, `Try`, and `Either` as needed:

```
object OptionTryEitherConversions {
    implicit class EitherToTry[L <: Throwable, R](val e: Either[L, R]) extends AnyVal {
        def toTry: Try[R] = e.fold(Failure(_), Success(_))
    }

    implicit class TryToEither[T](val t: Try[T]) extends AnyVal {
        def toEither: Either[Throwable, T] = 
          t.map(Right(_)).recover(Left(_)).get
    }

    implicit class OptionToTry[T](val o: Option[T]) extends AnyVal {
        def toTry(throwable: Throwable): Try[T] = 
          o.map(Success(_)).getOrElse(Failure(throwable))
    }
}
```

This would allow you to do:

```
import OptionTryEitherConversions._

//Try to Either
Try(1).toEither //Either[Throwable, Int] = Right(1)
Try("foo".toInt).toEither //Either[Throwable, Int] = Left(java.lang.NumberFormatException)

//Either to Try
Right[Throwable, Int](1).toTry //Success(1)
Left[Throwable, Int](new Exception).toTry //Failure(java.lang.Exception)

//Option to Try
Some(1).toTry(new Exception) //Success(1)
(None: Option[Int]).toTry(new Exception) //Failure(java.lang.Exception)
```

Answer (score 9):

`Either` can be seen as a generalization of `Option`.
If you fix the first value of `Either`, for example by setting it to `Unit`, you would get something that behaves in essentially the same way as `Option`:

```
Option[X] := Either[Unit, X]
```

In this case, `Left[Unit, X]` would correspond to `None`, and `Right[Unit, X]` would correspond to `Some[X]`.

For `Option[X]`, `None` would signal some kind of failure to obtain a value of type `X`, and `Some[X]` would signal success.
For `Either[Unit, X]`, instance of type `Left[Unit, X]` would represent failure, and `Right[Unit, X]` would represent success.

However, you can use the first component of `Either` to store more detailed information about *why* something failed, or some additional information that helps you to recover from an error. `Option` gives you just a `None`, which is not very useful.
But `Either[F,X]` could return either a success value `Right[F, X]`, which is essentially just a wrapper for `X`, or a detailed description of failure in `Left[F, X]`, with a value of type `F` representing the failure.

This allows you to define more sophisticated recovery strategies. 
For example, take a look at [`Form.scala`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/data/Form.scala) of the Play!-Framework. 
They use `Either` all over the place, because they want to either respond to user's form submission, or to send back a partially filled form, annotated with helpful error messages. The alternative to this would be to work with `Option[TypeOfFormContent]`, which would evaluate to `None` if some of the form fields contained invalid input. This in turn would mean that the user gets something like "Bad Request. Please fill the whole form again." as response, which would be utterly annoying. Therefore, `Either` is used instead of `Option`, because it can actually keep track of what exactly went wrong with the form submission.

The disadvantage of `Either` is that it is not a monad: in order to work with it effectively, you always have to pass two different callbacks for the two different cases. This can result in a "callback-hell". Therefore, one should think carefully whether an exact description of the failure is that valuable. In the case of a failed form submission, a detailed description of the failure is valuable, because one does not want to force the user to retype everything again. In other cases, `Option` might be more appropriate, because one does not want to force the programmers to deal with unnecessary detailed descriptions of unrecoverable errors.

Comment: Andrey Tyukin has returned! I have to admit though—I'm a little disappointed that you didn't put together [another awesome diagram](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19739576/1427124) for your answer.

Comment: @DaoWen: I guess I definitely should do something about my "internet-alter-ego", because currently it seems as if a ridiculous gif-painting of a burning vegan panda is the second most important idea I've ever had. Gonna do something about it in three months or so.