# What is the difference between Try and Either?

Tags: scala

According to [the documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.4/index.html#scala.util.Try):

> The Try type represents a computation that may either result in an
>   exception, or return a successfully computed value. It's similar to,
>   but semantically different from the scala.util.Either type.

The docs do not go into further detail as to what the semantic difference is.  Both seem to be able to communicate successes and failures.  Why would you use one over the other?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I covered the relationship between `Try`, `Either`, and `Option` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29682208/what-are-the-differences-between-either-and-option/29683007#29683007).  The highlights from there regarding the relationship between `Try` and `Either` are summarized below:

`Try[A]` is isomorphic to `Either[Throwable, A]`.  In other words you can treat a `Try` as an `Either` with a left type of `Throwable`, and you can treat any `Either` that has a left type of `Throwable` as a `Try`.   It is conventional to use `Left` for failures and `Right` for successes.

Of course, you can also use `Either` more broadly, not only in situations with missing or exceptional values.  There are other situations where `Either` can help express the semantics of a simple union type (where value is one of two types).

Semantically, you might use `Try` to indicate that the operation might fail.  You might similarly use `Either` in such a situation, especially if your "error" type is something other than `Throwable` (e.g. `Either[ErrorType, SuccessType]`).  And then you might also use `Either` when you are operating over a union type (e.g. `Either[PossibleType1, PossibleType2]`).

Since Scala 2.12, the standard library does include the conversions from `Either` to `Try` or from `Try` to `Either`. For earlier versions, it is pretty simple to enrich  `Try`, and `Either` as needed:

```
object TryEitherConversions {
    implicit class EitherToTry[L <: Throwable, R](val e: Either[L, R]) extends AnyVal {
        def toTry: Try[R] = e.fold(Failure(_), Success(_))
    }

    implicit class TryToEither[T](val t: Try[T]) extends AnyVal {
        def toEither: Either[Throwable, T] = 
          t.map(Right(_)).recover(Left(_)).get
    }
}
```

This would allow you to do:

```
import TryEitherConversions._

//Try to Either
Try(1).toEither //Either[Throwable, Int] = Right(1)
Try("foo".toInt).toEither //Either[Throwable, Int] = Left(java.lang.NumberFormatException)

//Either to Try
Right[Throwable, Int](1).toTry //Success(1)
Left[Throwable, Int](new Exception).toTry //Failure(java.lang.Exception)
```

Answer (score 11):

To narrowly answer your question: "What's the *semantic difference*":

This probably refers to flatMap and map, which are non-existent in Either and either propagate failure or map the success value in Try.  This allows, for instance, chaining like

```
for { 
   a <- Try {something} 
   b <- Try {somethingElse(a)}
   c <- Try {theOtherThing(b)}
} yield c
```

which does just what you'd hope - returns a Try containing either the first exception, or the result.

Try has lots of other useful methods, and of course its companion apply method, that make it very convenient for its intended use - exception handling.

If you really want to be overwhelmed, there are two other classes out there which may be of interest for this kind of application.  [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) has a class called "[\/](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Either.html)" (formerly known as Prince), pronounced "Either", which is mostly like Either, but flatMap and map work on the Right value.  Similarly, and not, [Scalactic](http://www.scalactic.org/) has an "[Or](http://www.scalactic.org/user_guide/OrAndEvery)" which is also similar to Either, but flatMap and map work on the Left value.

I don't recommend Scalaz for beginners.

Comment: Your first paragraphs says it all. Lots of solutions look the same when we look at them from an static / structure-driven point of view. But when we starting thinking in terms of what then mean they are radically different.

Comment: Worth mentioning that methods like `map`, `flatMap`, and `filter` are available on `LeftProjection` and `RightProjection` (which are accessible through `myEither.right` and `myEither.left`).  This allows you to chain `Either` operations in a `for` comprehension similarly to what is shown here with `Try`.  This answer shows an example of such a usage, with its analogous `Try` version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29682208/what-are-the-differences-between-either-and-option/29683007#29683007

Comment: In Scala 2.12, [`Either` is right-biased](https://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0/#either-is-now-right-biased).
It supports operations like `map`, `flatMap`, `contains`, `toOption`, and so forth, which operate on the right-hand side.

Comment: The most important takeaway from this answer is the last sentence, "I don't recommend Scalaz for beginners."

Answer (score 4):

`Either` does not imply success and failure, it is just a container for either an A or a B.  It is common to use it to represent successes and failures, the convention being to put the failure on the left side, and the success on the right.

A `Try` can be seen as an `Either` with the left-side type set to `Throwable`. `Try[A]` would be equivalent to `Either[Throwable, A]`.

Use `Try` to clearly identify a potential failure in the computation, the failure being represented by an exception.  If you want to represent the failure with a different type (like a String, or a set of case classes extending a sealed trait for example) use `Either`.

Answer (score 2):

`Either` is more general, since it simply represents disjoint unions of types. 
In particular, it can represent a union of valid return values of some type `X` and `Exception`. However, it does not attempt to catch any exceptions on its own. You have to add try-catch blocks around dangerous code, and then make sure that each branch returns an appropriate subclass of `Either` (usually: `Left` for errors, `Right` for successful computations).

`Try[X]` can be thought of as `Either[Exception, X]`, but it also catches Exceptions on its own.

Answer (score 2):

`Either[X, Y]` usage is more general. As its name say it can represent either an object of X type or of Y.

`Try[X]` has only one type and it might be either a Success[X] or a Failure (which contains a `Throwable`).

At some point you might see `Try[X]` as an `Either[Throwable,X]`

What is nice about `Try[X]` is that you can chain futher operations to it, if it is really a Success they will execute, if it was a Failure they won't

```
val connection = Try(factory.open())
val data = connection.flatMap(conn => Try(conn.readData()))
//At some point you can do 
data matches {
  Success(data) => print data
  Failure(throwable) => log error
}
```

Of course, you can always oneline this like

```
Try(factory.open()).flatMap(conn => Try(conn.readData()) matches {
      Success(data) => print data
      Failure(throwable) => log error
}
```

Comment: Not sure why the downvote, care to give us some enlightment about it?

Answer (score 2):

As already have been mentioned, `Either` is more general, so it might not only wrap error/successful result, but also can be used as an alternative to `Option`, for branching the code path.

For abstracting the effect of an error, only for this purpose, I identified the following differences:

1. `Either` can be used to specify a description of the error, which can be shown to the client. `Try` - wraps an exception with a stack trace, less descriptive, less client oriented, more for internal usage.
2. `Either` allows us to specify error type, with existing `monoid` for this type. As a result, it allows us to combine errors (usually via applicative effects). `Try` abstraction with its exception, has no `monoid` defined. With `Try` we must spent more effort to extract error and handle it.

   Based on it, here is my best practices:
   When I want to abstract effect of error, I always use `Either` as the first choice, with `List`/`Vector`/`NonEmptyList` as error type.

   `Try` is used only, when you invoke code, written in OOP. Good candidates for `Try` are methods, that might throw an exception, or methods, that sends request to external systems (rest/soap/database requests in case the methods return a raw result, not wrapped into FP abstractions, like `Future`, for instance.