# why does cat's effect async signature uses Either[Throwable, A] and not Try[A]?

Tags: scala, error-handling, functional-programming, scala-cats

Long time back we had long debate within our team on using `Try[A]` vs `Either[Throwable, A]` and we ended up choosing `Try[A]` because those are semantically same when left side of `Either` is `Throwable`. That time I was searching for a codebase where `Either[Throwable, A]` is used but I couldn't find any.

But today while watching Fabio Labella's talk on [How do Fibers Work? A Peek Under the Hood](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x5_MmZVLiSM), 
following signature struck my mind

```
    def async[A](k: (Either[Throwable, A] => Unit) => Unit): F[A]
```

So my question is, Is there any specific reason for using `Either[Throwable, A]` instead of `Try[A]`? Which one is recommended?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29779352/2928853

Comment: Exactly `Try[A]` is isomorphic to `Either[Throwable, A]`. My question is, Is there any reason of using `Either[Throwable, A]` or it is just individuals choice?

Comment: this may somehow related to the fact that Try is not a Monad (almost monad but not exactly). Cats is pure functional programming library, so they probably decided to use pure functional structures.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure semantics are entirely isomorphic between `Try[A]` and `Either[Throwable, A]`. For example, we can change the bias of `Either`

```
val e: Either[Throwable, Int] = Left(new Exception("boom"))
for (s <- e.left) yield s.getMessage.length
res5: scala.util.Either[Int,Int] = Left(4)
```

or swap the sides

```
e.swap
res6: scala.util.Either[Int,Throwable] = Right(java.lang.Exception: boom)
```

Consider some unusual scenario where we consider `Throwable`s to actually be the *expected* result and hence would want them on the `Right` side. Perhaps we are building some pure-functional testing library where we want to provide an API for asserting on exceptions. One could imagine encoding these semantics as `Either[A, Throwable]`.

Another potential advantage of `Either` over `Try` might be cats providing more extension methods for it. For example, consider all the goodies in `import cats.syntax.either._` whilst I am not aware of similar for `Try`. Say we want to accumulate all the errors in a list instead of short-circuit, then we can simply `traverse(_.toValidatedNec)` like so

```
import cats.syntax.either._
import cats.instances.list._
import cats.syntax.traverse._

val l: List[Either[Throwable, Int]] = List(Right(1), Right(2), Left(new RuntimeException("boom")), Right(3), Left(new RuntimeException("crash")))
l.traverse(_.toValidatedNec)
res0: cats.data.ValidatedNec[Throwable,List[Int]] = Invalid(Chain(java.lang.RuntimeException: boom, java.lang.RuntimeException: crash))
```

To achieve similar with `Try` I think we would have to work harder.

Answer (score 0):

Skimming the answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29779135/2928853), here is a list of differences:

- Either does not imply success and failure, it is just a container for either an A or a B
- Use Try to clearly identify a potential failure in the computation, the failure being represented by an exception
- What is nice about Try[X] is that you can chain futher operations to it, if it is really a Success they will execute, if it was a Failure they won't
- Try has lots of other useful methods, and of course its companion apply method, that make it very convenient for its intended use - exception handling.
- Either can be used to specify a description of the error, which can be shown to the client. Try - wraps an exception with a stack trace
- Good candidates for Try are methods, that might throw an exception, or methods, that sends request to external systems