# Scala retry sequence of futures until they all complete

Tags: scala, future, retry-logic

In scala, how would you write a function that takes a Sequence of Futures, runs them all, continually retries any that fail, and returns the results?

For example, the signature might be:

```
  def waitRetryAll[T](futures: Seq[Future[T]]): Future[Seq[T]]
```

Bonus points for a configurable timeout at which point the function fails and the callee can handle that case.
Bonus bonus points if that error case handler can receive the list of Futures that failed.

Thanks!

Comment: Well... retries without a limit and backoff seems like a nice way for shooting your self in both feet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [Retry a function that returns a Future](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59033404/5205022) consider

```
def retry[T](expr: => Future[T], n: Int = 3): Future[Either[Throwable, T]] = {
  Future
    .unit
    .flatMap(_ => expr).map(v => Right(v))
    .recoverWith {
      case _ if n > 1 => retry(expr, n - 1)
      case e => Future.failed(e).recover{case e => Left(e)}
    }
}
```

in combination with

```
Future.sequence
```

which converts `List[Future[T]]` to `Future[List[T]]`. However `sequence` has fail-fast behaviour, thus we had to lift our `Future[T]` to `Future[Either[Throwable, T]]`

Putting these pieces together we can define

```
def waitRetryAll[T](futures: List[() => Future[T]]): Future[List[Either[Throwable, T]]] = {
  Future.sequence(futures.map(f => retry(f.apply())))
}
```

and use it like so

```
val futures = List(
  () => Future(42),
  () => Future(throw new RuntimeException("boom 1")),
  () => Future(11),
  () => Future(throw new RuntimeException("boom 2"))
)

waitRetryAll(futures)
  .andThen { case v => println(v) }
```

which outputs

```
Success(List(Right(42), Left(java.lang.RuntimeException: boom 1), Right(11), Left(java.lang.RuntimeException: boom 2)))
```

We can `collect` our `Left`s or `Right`s and recover or continue processing accordingly, for example

```
waitRetryAll(futures)
  .map(_.collect{ case v if v.isLeft => v })
  ...
```

Note how we had to pass in `List[() => Future[T]]` instead of `List[Future[T]]` in order to prevent the futures from eagerly kicking-off.

Comment: Any reason for `Either` instead of a `Try`?

Comment: Thanks @mario-galic I'm probably doing something wrong, but with this test case https://pastebin.com/ra0TLg4a to me it looks like this doesn't retry the failed calls.  The test calls waitRetryAll with a function that returns only after the 3rd try. Is my test function `doItEventually`, which returns a value or throws an exception within the Future, valid for these functions?

Comment: @Jethro You are absolutely right, there was a major error in my implementation! Thank you for testing it. Please see edited answer with my latest attempt. Notice I am passing `List[() => Future[T]]` instead of `List[Future[T]]` in order to prevent the futures from eagerly kicking-off. Try it in scastie https://scastie.scala-lang.org/c1agpT5PSki8PX3C0GfYKw

Comment: @ig-dev Solution with [`Try`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29344937/5205022) would work just as well. There is no particular reason I used `Either`, it was just to demonstrate a potential solution. Perhaps an advantage may be scala-cats provides more goodies to work with `Either`. This could be due to, theoretically, `Try` not being a monad: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58103898/why-does-cats-effect-async-signature-uses-eitherthrowable-a-and-not-trya

Answer (score 3):

As far as I remember in standard library there are no utilities for `Future` timeout.

How would you interrupt/cancel ongoing computation on JVM? In general case, you cannot, you can only interrupt `Thread` when it's on `wait` but if it never `wait`s? IO libraries for async computation (which define cancelation) executes IO as series of smaller non-interruptible tasks (each map/flatMap creates a new step) and if they receive cancel/timeout then they will continue executing current task (as they cannot stop it) but they won't start the next one. You could return exception on timeout, but still the last step would be executed so if it was some side-effect (e.g. DB operation) it would be completed after you already returned failure.

This is non-intuitive and tricky and I think it was the reason why this behavior wasn't added to standard library.

Additionally, future is ongoing, potentially side-effecting operation. You cannot take a value of type `Future[A]` and rerun it. You could however pass future as by-name parameter, so that in `.recoverWith` you could create the future anew.

That being sad you could implement something like "retry until the LocalDateTime.now - startTime >= " because this is what I think you want:

```
def retry[A](future: => Future[A], attemptsLeft: Int, timeoutTime: Instant) =
  future.recoverWith {
    case error: Throwable =>
      if (attemptsLeft <= 0 || Instant.now.isAfter(timeoutTime)) Future.failure(error)
      else retryHelper(future, attemptsLeft - 1, timeoutTime)
  }
```

That can be combined with `Future.sequence` to create a list of results:

```
def retryFutures[A](list: List[() => Future[A]) = {
  val attempts: Int = ...
  val timeout: Instant = ...
  Future.sequence(list.map(future => retry(future(), attempts, timeout)))
}
```

If you want to keep trace of which future failed and which succeeded:

```
def futureAttempt[A](future: Future[A]): Future[Either[Throwable, A]] =
  future.map(a => Right(a))).recover {
    case error: Throwable => Left(error)
  }

def retryFutures[A](list: List[() => Future[A]) = {
  val attempts: Int = ...
  val timeout: Instant = ...
  Future.sequence(list.map(future => retry(futureAttempt(future()), attempts, timeout)))
}
```

If you don't troubled with cancelling futures on JVM and if you have more cases like that I would suggest using a library.

If you want to use something that implements retry for you there is [cats-retry](https://github.com/cb372/cats-retry)

If you want to have something better that `Future` at defining computation (e.g. something which won't require you to use by-name params or nullary functions) try out [Monix](https://monix.io/) or ZIO (https://zio.dev/)