# Functional way to throw an exception if error and return nothing if success

Tags: scala, exception, functional-programming

I have a method `validateSyntax` that throws an exception if the syntax of a statement is invalid, but does not need to return any information if the syntax is correct.

```
def validateSyntax(statement: String): Unit = {
  if (! is_valid(statement)) throw new Exception("syntax is not valid")
}
```

Then I call it from the Main:

```
val myStatements = List("foo =! bar", "print(foo + bar)")
myStatements.foreach(stmt => validateSyntax(stmt))
```

I want that my program exits and throws the exception if one of the statements is invalid

For the moment I set the return type of `validateSyntax` to `Unit` but I am not sure it is the functional way to do it.

Is there any more idiomatic way to do it ?

Comment: Could you please explain the downvote so that I don't repeat the mistake ?

Comment: I didn't downvote. But you might want to check [mcve] and [how to ask](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get good feedback, you need to show your code.

Comment: I supposed my question concerns only the signature of the function and one does not need to know its body. I edited my question with minimal code that illustrates my case

Comment: Throwing an exception is a side effect and as such your code is not functional. You may refactor this using **Either** or **Try** or even **Option** but we would need to know more about your use case.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I edited my description

Comment: You can wrap exceptions in a `scala.util.Try`. Take a look at the example in [scala.util.Try](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Try.html) page. That should get you started.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29779135/what-is-the-difference-between-try-and-either) to understand all the differences between the options you have to handle this functionally.

Answer (score 3):

Throwing exception is not idiomatic way to deal with errors in Scala, because of variety of reasons, like:

- Scala does not have `checked` exceptions concept like Java, all exceptions from Scala perspective are `unchecked` - so compiler will not force you to handle certain exception, hence it easier to do a mistake and forget to handle exception;
- Exceptions considered as side effects and function throwing them are considered as impure. It does not mean they bad or not properly designed, it means, they should be handled in a special manner, hence might make your code more complicated without meaningful reason. (it is long discussion out of scope of this question);
- Error should be an return value - if you would like to force client side to handle expected error, proper result type should be choose;

So in you case you can go with next possible options:

- User plain `Either[String, Unit]` - where `Left` instance will represent some error, and `Right` only the fact that validation passed.
- Use `cats` `Validated` - see for more details official docs: https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/validated.html
- Use `refined` library which along with plain validation, provide type level prove that some entity is valid. See project page for more details: https://github.com/fthomas/refined

In case of using plain `Either` the solution will look like:

```
  def validateSyntax(statement: String): Either[String, Unit] = {
    if (!is_valid(statement)) Left("syntax is not valid") else Right(())
  }

  val myStatements = List("foo =! bar", "print(foo + bar)")
  val validatedStatements = myStatements.map(statement => statement -> validateSyntax(statement))
  val allErrors = validatedStatements.collect {
    case (statement, Left(error)) => s"Statement: `$statement` is invalid because of $error"
  }

  if(allErrors.nonEmpty) {
    println(s"Statements not valid. All errors:\n - ${allErrors.mkString("\n - ")}")
    sys.exit(-1)
  }
```

which produce next example output:

```
Statements not valid. All errors:
 - Statement: `foo =! bar` is invalid because of syntax is not valid
 - Statement: `print(foo + bar)` is invalid because of syntax is not valid
```

If you would like to produce more precise error message, and validate each statement over more then one rule, then `cats` `Validated` mentioned before might be the option to go. Please, see implementation example below:

```
  import cats.data._
  import cats.data.Validated._
  import cats.instances.string._
  import cats.instances.unit._
  import cats.syntax.show._
  import cats.syntax.validated._
  import cats.syntax.foldable._

  type InvalidNec[T] = Invalid[NonEmptyChain[T]]

  type ValidatedStatement = (String, ValidatedNec[String, String])
  type InvalidStatement = (String, InvalidNec[String])

  implicit def listShow[T](implicit show: Show[T]): Show[List[T]] = Show.show(_.map(show.show).mkString("\n"))
  implicit val invalidNecShow: Show[InvalidNec[String]] = Show.show(_.e.mkString_("\n - ", "\n - ", ""))
  implicit val invalidStatementShow: Show[InvalidStatement] = Show.show {
    case (statement, invalid) =>  show"Statement `$statement` is invalid, because of next errors: $invalid"
  }

  def validateRule1(statement: String): ValidatedNec[String, Unit] = {
    val validCondition: Boolean = false // put validation condition here
    if(validCondition) ().validNec else "Statement does not satisfy first rule1".invalidNec
  }

  def validateRule2(statement: String): ValidatedNec[String, Unit] = {
    val validCondition: Boolean = false // put validation condition here
    if(validCondition) ().validNec else "Statement does not satisfy first rule2".invalidNec
  }

  def validateSyntax(statement: String): ValidatedNec[String, String] = {
    (validateRule1(statement) combine validateRule2(statement)).map(_ => statement)
  }

  val myStatements = List("foo =! bar", "print(foo + bar)")
  val validatedStatements: List[ValidatedStatement] = myStatements.map(statement => statement -> validateSyntax(statement))

  val invalidStatements: List[InvalidStatement] = validatedStatements.collect {
    case (statement, invalid: InvalidNec[String]) => statement -> invalid
  }

  if (invalidStatements.nonEmpty) {
    println(show"$invalidStatements")
    sys.exit(-1)
  }
```

Which produce next output result (just an example):

```
Statement `foo =! bar` is invalid, because of next errors: 
 - Statement does not satisfy first rule1
 - Statement does not satisfy first rule2
Statement `print(foo + bar)` is invalid, because of next errors: 
 - Statement does not satisfy first rule1
 - Statement does not satisfy first rule2
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Either` to encode errors on the `Left` and a valid result on the `Right`.

```
def validateSyntax(statement: String): Either[String, Unit] = {
  if (is_valid(statement)) Right(())
  else Left("syntax is not valid")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
type Error = String
type Statement = String
type Statements = List[Statement]
type ErrorOr[A] = Either[Error, A]

def validateSyntax(statement: Statement): Option[Error] =
  if (is_valid(statement)) None
  else Some("syntax is not valid")

def ensureAllAreValid(statements: Statements): ErrorOr[Statements] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(remaining: Statements, acc: Statements): ErrorOr[Statements] =
    remaining match {
      case statement :: tail =>
        validateSyntax(statement) match {
          case Some(error) =>
            Left(error)

          case None =>
            loop(
              remaining = tail,
              statement :: acc
            )
        }

      case Nil =>
        // If the order is not important,
        // Remove the reverse which is somewhat costly.
        Right(acc.reverse)
    }

    loop(remaining = statements, acc = List.empty)
  }
}

def main(): Unit = {
  val myStatements = List("foo =! bar", "print(foo + bar)")
  ensureAllAreValid(myStatements) match {
    case Left(error) =>
      println(error)
      system.exit(-1)

    case Right(statements) =>
      ???
  }
}
```